# framerate issue with ffmpeg zoompan filter

Tags: video, ffmpeg

with a lot of searching on this board, I've been able to put the following ffmpeg command together. It creates a clip of an image scaling from 1.00 -> 1.12x over 240 frames @ 24p (10 seconds).

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i myphoto.jpg -vf \"zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0005,1.12)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=240\" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 10 -s hd1080 -r 24 -crf 10 myvideo.mp4
```

However, when this command is ran, I get a 10 second clip, with the zoompan 'resetting' to 1.00x at around 9.5 seconds. Upon checking the rendered video in Quicktime's video inspector, I'm finding the FPS to equal 23.7, not the 24 I've set with `-r 24`. Am I looking over something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are treated as 25 fps unless specified, and the zoompan filter also has a private fps option that determines its output. So use,

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -i myphoto.jpg -vf \"zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0005,1.12)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=240:s=hd1080:fps=24\" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 10 -crf 10 myvideo.mp4
```

(Also, zoompan has its own size option, so you should set that within the filter else there will be two scaling operations)

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't seem to make much of a difference with the 'zoom out' back to 1.00x @ 9 sec,13 frames.

Comment: Corrected command